# Subalgebra of group algebra generated by idempotents

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-number-theory, group-algebras

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $A$ and $B$ be two abelian subgroups of $G$. Let $K$ be a number field such that all characters of $A$ and of $B$ take values in $K$. Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K$. Write $\{e_1,\ldots, e_n\}$ for the set of primitive idempotents of $KA$ and $\{f_1,\ldots, f_m\}$ for the set of primitive idempotents of $KB$.

Assume now that the $\mathcal{O}_K$-algebra generated by $\{e_1,\ldots, e_n,f_1,\ldots f_m\}$ is a finite $\mathcal{O}_K$-module.

**Question**: Must $A$ and $B$ commute under this assumption?

Edit: here is a motivating example: When both $A$ and $B$ are of order 2, the group they generate is isomorphic to $D_{2n}$ for some $n$. By considering some irreducible representations, the finiteness of the algebra becomes equivalent to the integrality of $\cos(\pi/n)$, and I believe this is not an algebraic integer for $n>2$.

Comment: Do you have some nice example where it is not finite?

Comment: How about $S_3$, $A=<(1,2)>$, $B=<(1,3)>$, $K=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: This $S_3$ case is not integral- when you apply the 2-dimensional irreducible character of $S_3$ to $1/2(1+(12))(1/2(1+(23))$ you get 1/4, so the $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra they generate cannot be a finite $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Comment: What happens in the Heisenberg case? That should be pretty typical.

Comment: @Kapil If you take the two non-commuting abelian subgroups then the algebra they generate is not a finite $\mathcal{O}_K$-module. One can see this by taking a matrix representation on which the center acts non-trivially

Comment: Isn’t $\cos(2\pi/k)$ always an algebraic integer by looking at Chebyshev polynomials?  So k=2n gives your $\cos(\pi/n)$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg , from what I gathered $2\cos(\pi/k)$ is an algebraic integer, but $\cos(\pi/k)$ is not. Think of k=6, you get $\sqrt{3}/2$, which is not an algebraic integer, but once you multiply it by 2 it becomes one.

Comment: Sorry chebyshev polynomials maybe are not monic